# SP Services does not update the list item

Tags: jquery, spservices

SP Services : UpdateListItems does not update the list item. The problem lies with the value that needs to be updated. The item is updated when the value is a normal text, but when it has some special characters like '&' the update doesn't work.

Any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't with SPServices. The problem is we are trying to use reserved characters.

Try using the following functions,

`escapeColumnValue("Yourvalue")`

```
// Escape column values
function escapeColumnValue(s) {
    return s.replace(/&(?![a-zA-Z]{1,8};)/g, "&");
    //(/&/g,'&');
}
```

OR

`xmlencode("yourvalue");`

[Source](http://spservices.codeplex.com/workitem/8632)

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: I modified your function as follows and it worked fine: function xmlencode(string) { return string.replace(/\&/g,'&'+'amp;');}

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to anyone, I had a similar problem with the `<` character, which is also reserved. The replace function wasn't working because the encoding for `<` is `&lt;`, so I used `replace(/</g, '&' + 'amp;' + 'lt;')` and it worked.